# Can I prevent the Puppetmaster from putting me in an Iron Maiden?

Tags: castlevania-harmony-of-despair

In *Castlevania: Harmony of Despair*, the Puppetmaster (Chapter 2) has this awful ability in which he places a voodoo doll into an iron maiden, which then swaps places with you, leaving you to take the 130+ damage from said iron maiden.

**Is there any way to prevent this from happening? If so, how?**

Comment: I would've picked a clearer tag. I thought for a second there's an HD remake of the 1st Castlevania I wasn't aware of...

Comment: I tagged it that way for a reason. "castlevania-hod" brings up Harmony of Dissonance results in Google, while "castlevania-hd" brings up Harmony of Despair. Also, the official name is [Castlevania HD](http://marketplace.xbox.com/en-US/Product/Castlevania-HD/66acd000-77fe-1000-9115-d80258410a7a).

Comment: Noted. I rolled back the change I've made.

Comment: Who does **not** want to be put into an Iron Maiden???? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DQW9wD00Twc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this Castlevania wiki article](http://castlevania.wikia.com/wiki/Puppet_Master), you should be able to destroy the doll before he's able to place it in the iron maiden:

> If he's within reach of an iron maiden, he will create a puppet in his hand, **the player must strike the doll 3 times in Normal mode and more in Hard mode before he throws the puppet into the maiden**, teleporting the player to that location and doing massive damage in the process.

Comment: Also, throughout the level you can move boxes to block the various iron maidens scattered around. That way you limit the number of them available.

Comment: There are a total of 8 caskets from what I can tell. 2 of them are in the middle where you have to take the first half of the puppet master's health. There are 3 of them that have crates nearby that can be pushed in front of them to eliminate them from use. Given that you pushed all the crates, you only have to worry about the final 3 caskets after the puppet master starts moving around. 2 of them are near the middle, the third should be accessible as long as you did not kill those 4 bone things in the large room to the left of the middle with the giant balance.